# How to create a measure in PowerPivot based on dynamic date range

Tags: excel, powerpivot

I have a monthly sales amount PowerPivot in excel (Please refer to the picture link 'Monthly sales amount' below). How do I create a measure in the PowerPivot to sum up the sales amount in the recent 3 months?

Thank you,

Noah

[Monthly sales amount](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCIPM.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you mean calendar months when you say recent three months. So whatever month you are looking at, you want the sum of that calendar month and the previous two calendar months (as opposed to last 90 days. You can use the following calculated measure to get the last 3 months sales.

```
Last 3 months sales:= 
 CALCULATE(SUM(Sales[Amt]),DATESINPERIOD(Sales[Date],LASTDATE(Sales[Date]),-3,MONTH))
```

There are other ways to do this if you have a date table, but if you have just the one table of data the above formula will work.